# build llvm clang4.0 for android armeabi

Tags: android, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to build llvm and clang4.0 for android armeabi.

Currently I have done these:
1. from:
http://hardenedlinux.org/toolchains/2016/04/01/How_to_build_Clang_toolchains_for_Android.html
I have checkout source code :

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b llvm  
repo sync
python external/clang/build.py
```

The build is going successful, but it will consume over 100G diskspace and about 8 hours. what's more, it is not clang 4.0.

2.
from http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html
I checked out the source code:

```
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
cd llvm/tools
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
cd llvm/projects
git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git
```

finally I build it with llvm/cmake/platforms/android.cmake
this android.cmake can be shown below:

```
# Toolchain config for Android NDK.
# This is expected to be used with a standalone Android toolchain (see
# docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html in the NDK on how to get one).
#
# Usage:
# mkdir build; cd build
# cmake ..; make
# mkdir android; cd android
# cmake -DLLVM_ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/path/to/android/ndk \
#   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../cmake/platforms/Android.cmake ../..
# make <target>

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

IF(NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER)
 SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin/clang)
ENDIF()

IF(NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)
 SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin/clang++)
ENDIF()

SET(ANDROID "1" CACHE STRING "ANDROID" FORCE)

SET(ANDROID_COMMON_FLAGS "-target arm-linux-androideabi --   sysroot=${LLVM_ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/sysroot -B${LLVM_ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${ANDROID_COMMON_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "toolchain_cflags"    FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${ANDROID_COMMON_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "toolchain_cxxflags" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-pie" CACHE STRING "toolchain_exelinkflags" FORCE)
```

But it always build x86 target, it does not build armeabi target.

My building host OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits.

Please How can I build llvm and clang 4.0 for armeabi targeting android ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're interested in cross-compiler targeting android. In this case  llvm/cmake/platforms/android.cmake is of no use (it's used for *building* via compiler, not building the compiler itself).

Please refer to http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html for generic LLVM build instructions. But in your case I believe you'd need to set LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD to "ARM;AArch64" and LLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE to "arm-linux-androideabi" in LLVM's cmake invocation.